# Subtracting a number from a variable throwing an error

Tags: shell, variables, grep, numbers, subtraction

I am using following code to grep the values that are calculated by adding and subtracting 1 from 2nd and 3rd column as follows:

```
 while read intron ; do
   start=$(grep -w $intron ../file_to_be_grepped_from | awk '{print $2}')
   end=$(grep -w $intron ../file_to_be_grepped_from | awk '{print $3}')
   str=$(($start-1))
   en=$(($end+1))
   grep -w $str ../file_to_be_grepped_from
   grep -w $en ../file_to_be_grepped_from
   echo $intron 
  done <  file
```

However the part where I am adding and subtracting 1 from 3rd and 2nd column respectively , I am getting an error as "46844234-1: syntax error in expression (error token is "46844234-1")" for a line in the file I am grepping from (file_to_be_grepped_from). The lines in the file from which they are grepped look like this:

```
  chr9  46844104    46844233    ENSG00000226007:E2  +
  chr9  46844104    46846023    ENSG00000226007:I2  +
  chr3  21584308    21584487    ENSG00000225542:E1  +
  chr3  21620681    21620873    ENSG00000225542:E2  +
```

I am trying to figure out if the error is because of duplicate rows or something else, I tried all the possible syntax for subtracting a number from the variable.

Comment: Which shell are you using?  Do you have the she-bang line on the top of your script? `#!/usr/bin/env bash`.  Another important thing - make sure to enclose your variables in double quotes, like `"$intron"` etc., to avoid surprises.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
str=$(grep -w $intron ../file_to_be_grepped_from | awk '{print($2-1)}')
en=$(grep -w $intron ../file_to_be_grepped_from | awk '{print($3+1)}')
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try:

```
start="101010"
end="999999"
let str=$start-1
let en=$end+1
echo $str     $en
     101009   1000000
```